# Word Field "Syntax Error"

Tags: vba, ms-word, field, mergefield

In a word file if have a field looking like:

```
{ = { IF "${COSTS}" = "" 0 "${COSTS}" } \# "#.0000" }
```

-> That gives my a Syntax Error!

However the following works fine:

```
{ = { IF "100" = "" 0 "100" } \# "#.0000" }
```

P.S: `${COSTS}` is a placeholder that is replaced automatically by a software tool.

What can I do here?

Comment: Can you verify that the {} in "${COSTS}" are 'ordinary' {} (that you can type on the keyboard, and that all the other {} are proper field code brace pairs (the ones you can insert with ctrl-F9)? Or maybe they are all field code brace pairs and the tool removes the {COSTS} fields? What does the Syntax error code actually say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the `IF` field as described by the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-IF-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e) is

```
{ IF Expression1 Operator Expression2 TrueText FalseText }
```

In your first example the field value will be the text `${COSTS}`, and not a number.

The syntax of the outer formula field according to the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-Formula-field-32d5c9de-3516-4ec3-80ed-d1fc2b5bc21d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is

```
{ = Formula [Bookmark ] [\#Numeric Picture ] }
```

The important part is the one about the formula (highlight by me):

> A formula is an expression that can contain any combination of numbers, bookmarks that refer to numbers, **fields resulting in numbers**, and the available operators and functions. The expression can refer to values in a table and values returned by functions.

In your first example, the inner field does not yield a number, hence the syntax error.

The solution will be to have the inner field return a number. Depending on where this number is coming from, this could e.g. be realized using bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the software that is replacing the code is having trouble with the spaces. Instead of putting #{COSTS} in quotes, try percent symbols? That works in batch. You should put what software your using to replace the code in your question.

Comment: Thx but changing ${COSTS} for #[COSTS] for instance does not work eather. So I tend to think it is an issue (maybe formatting) within word!?